# Classic ASP Auto Suggest Like Google

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, vbscript

While working on a project i came across a functionality in which i need to implement auto suggest textbox using classic asp. I did it and it works fine. I'm using XMLHttp Request object to pick the database column values when user enter something in textbox.

Everything works fine. But if the table have too many rows (37,000+) in it, the performance of the application decreases. Please suggest what steps should i take in order to improve the performance in this case.

Comment: Where exactly is performance bottleneck? You don't return to browser all 37000 possible suggestions, right?

Comment: its on database end, query take much much time to pick the records. I use select columnname from tablename where columnname like 'usertext%'.

Comment: If processing sql request is slow, then you need db-related solution. Try posting a question with 'sql' or similar tags. I would try creating column index, but I'm not db expert.  Generally, processing 37000 rows should be quite fast (assuming you don't return all 37000 rows to your application)

Comment: Yes quite true, Suppose user just typed A and there are more than 20K rows starting with latter A. then in that case number of returning rows are too much, But in that scenario @balexandre could also work, which is to limit the number of rows returning from database. Am working on this and will update here soon.

Comment: Why not ask the user to select an initial letter and only autoselect list for that letter? You can add buttons for each letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not just showing a `SELECT TOP 15 [name] ...`?

why do you need to show them all...

if someone enters "B" I really (as a user) don't expect you (the application) to show me all the possibilities.

...or am I wrong?

---

**P.S.** you need to start using something like jQuery ... in around 10 lines you would do the same as all your javascript code ;-)

---

***added***

It is normal to have the auto suggest box only start suggesting after the first 3 characters been typed ... try this first!

just add in your `showHint` method

```
if (str.length < 3) return;
```

Comment: Yes you are right about JQuery. But the actual culprit is on database end which takes time to execute the query and filter out the records.

Comment: what is actually your SQL Statement here? shouldn't be that big... And what db version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use indexes on the database fields that you have in your where-statement in the query and it will go much faster.